# Nuxt 3 on Gitlab Pages

Tags: gitlab, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy my static Nuxt 3 site on Gitlab pages, which I used to with Nuxt 2 changing the directory name **dist** to the gitlab requested **public**.

As Nuxt 3 now renamed what used to be called **static** with **public**, I cannot do the same change.

Nuxt 3 now generates the site inside **.output/public** so here is my `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
# The Docker image that will be used to build your app
  image: node:20.4.0
# Functions that should be executed before the build script is run
  before_script:
    - yarn install
  pages:
    script:
      - yarn generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      # The folder that contains the files to be exposed at the Page URL
      - .output/public
 rules:
   # This ensures that only pushes to the default branch will trigger
   # a pages deploy
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

I downloaded the artifacts after the pipeline fails and .output/public is there, including index.html inside /public.

I have also tried just 'public' as path, but in that case the artifacts will contain the actual public folder of nuxt (ex static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must generate the `public` artifact in the root of your workspace, not in `.output/`

If you have a conflicting path, you'll have to work around that. For example, you might remove the directory at the end of the job and replace it with the public dir from your output directory.

```yaml
pages:
  # ...
  script:
    - yarn generate
    - rm -rf ./public
    - mv ./.output/public ./public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Alternatively, you can do this in another job, if you want.

```yaml
generate:
  script:
    - yarn generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .output/public
    expire_in: 10 mins
pages:
  needs: [generate]
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - mv .output/public ./public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I adopted your first solution as it seemed more compact. The second might have its benefits, but I would not be able to tell :)
Again this was really helpful. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving files around in the pipeline, it's also possible to change the Nuxt/Nitro configuration.

First, rename your `./public` folder to `./static` (or any other name you prefer).

Then, change your `nuxt.config.ts` as such:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  dir: {
    // this is to prevent conflict with GitLab pages, which requires
    // the build output to be in the `./public` folder.
    public: "static",
  },
  nitro: {
    output: {
      // place static output in the ./public folder, for GitLab
      // pages to pick up
      publicDir: "public",
    },
  },
  // ...
})
```

This will make it so that GitLab pages can directly use the build artifacts from the `./public` folder, allowing you to use your original pipeline.

Here's the documentation for the configuration I used:

- https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#public
- https://nitro.unjs.io/config#output